# Larger subplots in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have 6 Y variables all with the same X Variable (time)

I want to have 6 plots in a column but when I use `subplot(6,1,1)` the plots become tiny vertically.

I have tried using:

```
x=0:360;
y1=sind(x);
y2=cosd(x);

h=subplot(6,1,1);
plot(x,y1);
d = get(h,'Position');
d(4)=d(4)*3;
set(h,'Position',d);

h=subplot(6,1,2);
plot(x,y2);
d = get(h,'Position');
d(4)=d(4)*3;
set(h,'Position',d);

....(For 6 subplots)
```

In the hope that each subplot would be 3 times larger vertically, which works but the spacing between the subplots does not update so the subplots start to overlap:

[image: example]

How can I make it so the subplots are larger vertically but equally spaced out like they were before I changed the height of each subplot?

Also if you could help me hide the xTick labels (numbers) but keep the ticks (lines) themselves on all subplots but the very bottom one that would also be a great help. Thanks!

Comment: This might work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112102/create-a-multiple-horizontal-line-plot-plotting-numerous-variable-for-multiple ? The data has to be properly setup for that.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab sucks pretty hard for easily making this kind of graphs. You either have to do it by hand or search around on the [file-exchange](http://www.mathworks.it/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) to see if someone already implemented something better.

This [blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2012/12/21/figure-margins-subplot-spacings-and-more/) discussed one script that seems to do what you want.

To hide the tick labels:

```
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', '')
```

If you want to build your own subplot, you can use something like this (not tested very well):

```
function ax = mySubplot(nrow, ncol)
% returns a matrix of axis handles
% to plot in the second subplot, you would use plot(ax(1,2), x, y)

% standard x, y, dx, dy for subplot(111)
x0 = 0.1300;
y0 = 0.1100;
w0 = 0.7750;
h0 = 0.8150;
w = w0 / ncol;
h = h0 / nrow;
figure()

ax = nan(nrow, ncol);
for irow = 1:nrow
    for icol = 1:ncol
        ax(irow, icol) = axes('position', ...
            [x0 + (icol - 1) * w, y0 + (nrow - irow) * h, 0.9*w, 0.9*h]);
    end
end
```

Result of mySubplot(6,2):
[image]

You could play yourself with the spacings.

Comment: Thanks for the XTickLabel help, Is there not a way I can use the set(gca,Position...) function to do this? It seems like im almost there I just need to add in some spacing between graphs

Comment: Yes, you could set the position by hand, you just need to calculate the correct value for the height :).

Comment: I added an example of how you could do it yourself.

Comment: The examples great, One slight problem though, when I change h0 to say for example 1 the top plot moves off the screen (see https://www.dropbox.com/s/c62x208uq32ym8i/untitled.png)

Comment: So don't do that, then! Note that you should keep `y0 + h0 <= 1`, but probably even less, since you want to keep some margin at the top of the figure.

Comment: How do i make the height of each subplot larger then if i don't change h0?

Comment: You could change `0.9*h` to `h` in my example code.